# How to validate typed message value in telebot telegram api?

Tags: python, telegram

I need only integers made up of **exactly** 12 digits.

```
def get_myfunc(message):
    global numb
    numb = message.text
    print (numb)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Specify your ID only digits')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, another_func)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use regex for it

```
import re
regex = re.compile('^[0-9]{12}$')
match = regex.match(message.text)
if match is None:
    raise Exception('message is not numeric or its length is not 12')
```

`^`: beginning of string

`[0-9]`: may only contains number from 0 until 9

`{12}`: number of occurence (in this case it refers to [0-9]) must be 12 (not less or more)

`$`: end of string

https://regex101.com/r/woMa46/1